# populating specific links from db table of logged in users only

Tags: php

I'm in the process of creating a CRUD application and the update and the links are populating well on the webpage.

What I'm trying to do is populate links that only pertain to the user that is logged in, and I'm not sure how to do this properly.

Here is a link to the website:

http://consolidatedgypsum.ca/cgs-new-site/admin/project-leads/index.php user: Test1 password: test1234 to get to the update page you'll need to click update reports.

this is my update page:

```
<?php include("includes/session.php"); ?>

<?php include("includes/reports_mysql_connect.php"); ?>
<?php


    $id = $_GET['id'];

    if(!isset($id)){
        $x = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM Reports ORDER BY timedate DESC") or die(mysql_error());
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($x)){
            $id = $row['id'];
        }
    }

    //step 3: user submits changes, updates DB to show new information
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $new_sale = $_POST['sale'];
        $new_questiontwo = $_POST['questiontwo'];
        $new_questionthree = $_POST['questionthree'];
        $new_questionfour = $_POST['questionfour'];
        $new_questionfive = $_POST['questionfive'];
        $new_questionsix = $_POST['questionsix'];
        $new_questionseven = $_POST['questionseven'];
        $new_questioneight = $_POST['questioneight'];

        echo "$new_sale | $new_questiontwo" ; 

        mysql_query("UPDATE Reports SET

            sale = '$new_sale',
            questiontwo = '$new_questiontwo',
            questionthree = '$new_questionthree',
            questionfour = '$new_questionfour',
            questionfive = '$new_questionfive',
            questionsix = '$new_questionsix',
            questionseven = '$new_questionseven',
            questioneight = '$new_questioneight'

            WHERE id = '$id' ") or die(mysql_error());
    }


    //step 1: Retrieve data to create links
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Reports ") or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $sale = $row['sale'];
        $questiontwo = $row['questiontwo'];
        $questionthree = $row['questionthree'];
        $questionfour = $row['questionfour'];
        $questionfive = $row['questionfive'];
        $questionsix = $row['questionsix'];
        $questionseven = $row['questionseven'];
        $questioneight = $row['questioneight'];

        //$id = $row['id'];
        //echo $id;

        echo '<div>' . $row['id'] . '<a href="updated-reports.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">' . $sale . '</a></div>';
    }

    //Step 2: Retrieve Data for selected report only to prepopulated form.

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Reports WHERE name='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        $thissale = $row['sale'];
        $thisquestiontwo = $row['questiontwo'];
        $thisquestionthree = $row['questionthree'];
        $thisquestionfour = $row['questionfour'];
        $thisquestionfive = $row['questionfive'];
        $thisquestionsix = $row['questionsix'];
        $thisquestionseven = $row['questionseven'];
        $thisquestioneight = $row['questioneight'];

        //$thisid = $row['id'];
        //echo $id;
    }

?>



<?php include("../includes/admin-leads-header.php") ?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="sixteen columns">
         <section class="fifteen columns">
            <div class="general">
                <div class="project-leads">

                    <?php

                        if($session->logged_in){
                        if($session->isAdmin()){
                        }

                        echo "<h3>Hello $session->username</h3>";
                        echo "<h5>Please enter your sales leads reports</h5>";
                    ?>

                    <div class="project-leads-reports">
                        <form name="contactform" id="contactform" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <span class="required">*</span>
                                    <label for="name">From: </label>
                                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $session->username?>" />
                                    <span class="error"></span>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <span class="required">*</span>
                                    <label for="email">E-mail Address: </label>
                                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php if($form->value("email") == ""){
                                            echo $session->userinfo['email'];
                                        }else{
                                            echo $form->value("email");
                                        }?>" />
                                    <span class="error"></span>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <span class="required">*</span>
                                    <label for="boss">Regional Sales Manager E-mail Address:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="boss" id="boss" value="<?php if($form->value("boss") == ""){
                                            echo $session->userinfo['boss'];
                                        }else{
                                            echo $form->value("boss");
                                        }?>" />
                                    <span class="error"></span>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <span class="required">*</span>
                                    <label for="Sales">Sales Lead Subject:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="sale" id="sale" value="<?php echo trim($thissale);?>" />
                                    <span class="error"></span>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <span class="required">*</span>
                                    <label for="questiontwo">When did you followup with the General Contractor?</label>
                                    <textarea name="questiontwo"  id="questiontwo" ><?php echo trim($thisquestiontwo);?></textarea>
                                    <span class="error"><?php echo $strValidationMessage2; ?></span>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <span class="required">*</span>
                                    <label for="questionthree">Who is/are the contractors working under the General Contractor?</label>
                                    <textarea name="questionthree" id="questionthree"><?php echo trim($thisquestionthree);?></textarea>
                                    <span class="error"><?php echo $strValidationMessage3; ?></span>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <span class="required">*</span>
                                    <label for="questionfour">Did the General Contractor have their own subcontractors, or did we refer our contractor customers to them?</label>
                                    <textarea name="questionfour"  id="questionfour"><?php echo trim($thisquestionfour);?></textarea>
                                    <span class="error"><?php echo $strValidationMessage4; ?></span>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <span class="required">*</span>
                                    <label for="questionfive">Can we or did we submit a price?</label>
                                    <textarea name="questionfive" id="questionfive" ><?php echo trim($thisquestionfive);?></textarea>
                                    <span class="error"><?php echo $strValidationMessage5; ?></span>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <span class="required">*</span>
                                    <label for="questionsix">Did we win and why did we win or did we lose or why did we lose?</label>
                                    <textarea name="questionsix" id="questionsix" ><?php echo trim($thisquestionsix);?></textarea>
                                    <span class="error"><?php echo $strValidationMessage6; ?></span>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <span class="required">*</span>
                                    <label for="questionseven">What is being done to progress any sales forward with this Project Lead?</label>
                                    <textarea name="questionseven" id="questionseven" ><?php echo trim($thisquestionseven);?></textarea>
                                    <span class="error"><?php echo $strValidationMessage7; ?></span>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <span class="required"></span>
                                    <label for="questioneight">Did you know about this project before it was assigned and or any additional comments?</label>
                                    <textarea name="questioneight"  id="questioneight"><?php echo trim($thisquestioneight);?></textarea>
                                    <span class="error"></span>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </form>
                    </div><!--end of project lead reports -->   


                <?php }?>



                </div><!--end of project-leads-->
            </div><!--end of general-->
        </section>
    </div> 
</div>


<?php include("../includes/admin_footer.php") ?>
```

Below are the table structures for the Reports, and the users, respectively.

[Valid XHTML http://consolidatedgypsum.ca/cgs-new-site/admin/project-leads/users.png](http://consolidatedgypsum.ca/cgs-new-site/admin/project-leads/users.png).
http://consolidatedgypsum.ca/cgs-new-site/admin/project-leads/users.png

[Valid XHTML http://consolidatedgypsum.ca/cgs-new-site/admin/project-leads/Reports.png](http://consolidatedgypsum.ca/cgs-new-site/admin/project-leads/Reports.png).
http://consolidatedgypsum.ca/cgs-new-site/admin/project-leads/Reports.png

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the only similar column between the two tables is email. Essentially, if you want all reports for a certain user, then each report must be related to a certain user (i.e., email column in Reports must equal to a specific email in Users). You'll need to have the user's email, most likely from a session, to modify your query:

```
'SELECT * FROM Reports WHERE email = ' . $_SESSION['email']
```

However, this isn't the best solution. If you're able and the reports each belong to a specific user, I would add the column userid to the reports table. Then you can run a query like this:

```
'SELECT * FROM Reports WHERE userid = ' . $_SESSION['userid']
```

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: Yes, you can add the column, but then you'll have to populate the column for each report with a userid.

Comment: if that's the case, is this going to have to executed in the future?

Comment: I have really stupid question, where am I suppose to executing this where clause?

Comment: You'll need to ensure that each report always has a specific userid tied to it, otherwise there's no way to restrict them to certain users. There isn't a way to join in an update; you'd have to run two update queries.

Comment: if I were to ensure that each report has a specific userid tied to it, I would manually have to go in everytime and put the id in?

Comment: You'd have to update whatever process creates the reports (probably an insert statement) to include the correct userid each time.